# OS X dynamic library shared data

Tags: multithreading, macos, dll, dynamic-library

now I research about dynamic library.

Actually I develop music plugin like vst, audio unit.

so I need to share data via plugin. (Because I can't handle process)

is there way to share data between plugin( not same, same plugin is possible)

I think plugin is shared library(like dll, but now I develop in OSX), so if shared libraries link again same another shared library.

it is like (process make thread before link shared library)

```
  thread1(shared library 1)   ->  
                                  X shared library( it has static variable) 
  thread2(shared library 2)   ->
```

they link X, but they had another value( different address, I think they have different data section )

but I studied 'shared library' share only code section?

so isn't it possible share data via library linking ( not in running process code)